# Sample comparison with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this example, I want compare population in USA versus China, over time.

```r
library(tidyverse)

population %>%
  filter(country %in% c("United States of America", "China")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = country, values_from = population) %>%
  rename(USA = `United States of America`) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = China, y = USA)) + geom_point(aes(col = year))
```

Is there a better way to do this (without using `pivot_wider`)? Or is this the right way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still what you want, but I'd expect th comparison between two population sizes over time to look something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

population %>%
  filter(country %in% c("United States of America", "China")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = population, color=country)) +
  geom_line() +
  expand_limits(y=0)
```

Returns:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I would like a dotplot (like on my little example). It works but I'm not convinced that going through the pivot is very suitable.

Comment: for a dotplot use `geom_point` instead of `geom_line`

Answer (score 0):

It is the right way *if* you want to show how the population of USA varies as a function of the population of China... but what's the sense of it? Probably what you want is to compare how the two population change as a function of time, then I think you'd be better off with a bar chart:

```r
library(tidyverse)
population %>%
  filter(country %in% c("United States of America", "China")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y=population, fill=country)) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I used the population dataset to have a reproducible example. But, in real life I want to compare gene expression between two samples. This is not really orderable like on a barplot. So I will keep my pivot ... Thank you!